# Use awk to split first line of a file based on delimiter and print others as it is

Tags: awk

I have an input file which looks like the below:

```
name<next>Rocky
id: 1321
age: 36
exp: 10
occupation: doctor
```

The requirement is to use awk in a way such that the output after awk processing is:

```
Rocky
id: 1321
age: 36
exp: 10
occupation: doctor
```

As can be seen the delimiter "" does not exist in other lines of the file except the first one.

As of now running below prints only Rocky followed by blank lines as there is no such delimiter in other lines:

```
awk -F "<next>" '{print $2}' file
```

I know awk processes line by line, but is there a way to restrict awk to process or perform the delimiting operation on only 1 line. In this case we are doing it on the first line. To generalize is it also possible to make awk process lines which match a criteria such as split lines with delimiter and print other lines as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk 'FNR==1{sub(/.*next>/,"")} 1'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

`FNR==1`: Checking condition here if line number is `1`. If yes then do following.

`{sub(/.*next>/,"")}`: Using `sub` utility of `awk` and substituting everything from starting to till `next>` with NULL here.

`1`: `awk` works on method of `condition` and then `action` so by mentioning `1` here I am making condition TRUE and not mentioning any action so by default print of current line will happen.

Answer (score 0):

you can print the last field, which will work with your delimiter, i.e.

```
$ awk -F'<next>' '{print $NF}' file

Rocky
id: 1321
age: 36
exp: 10
occupation: doctor
```